# How to create extensions for LaTeX?

Tags: macros

I want to create extensions in LaTeX. 
What I really want to do is be able to write `\myOwnCommand` and have something happen to it, like a new class and functions in programming.
It would be great to write the instructions of a game, for example `\dice3` and have a little image of a dice and the face with three dots appear.

I have seen people using `\newcommand{\ZZZZZZZ}{ZZZZZZ}`, but i'm not sure how to actually do it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: A little tutorial: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros

Comment: Did you try Googling "latex newcommand"?

Answer (score 1):

it's rather simple. [check it out](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/anton/latex/ltx-18.html)

and -by the way- your question belongs to TeX SE site which is only a hint for future tex/latex questions.

[TeX SE site](http://tex.stackexchange.com)